# Select conversations from a SQLite chatlog

Tags: sqlite

I have a SQLite table representing a chatlog. The two important columns for this question are 'content' and 'timestamp'.

I need to group the messages in the chatlog by conversations. Each message is only an individual line, so a conversation can be selected as each message joined by a new line using group_concat

```
group_concat(content, CHAR(10)
```

I want to identify a conversation by any messages which are within a length of time (such as 15 minutes) from each other. A conversation can be any length (including just an individual message, if there are no other messages within 15 minutes of it).

Knowing this, I can identify whether a message is the start or part of a conversation as

```
WHEN timestamp - LAG(timestamp, 1, timestamp) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp) < 900
```

But this is as far as I've gotten. I can make a column 'is_new_convo' using

```
WITH ordered_messages AS (
    SELECT content, timestamp
    FROM messages
    ORDER BY timestamp
), conversations_identified AS (
    SELECT *,
        CASE
            WHEN timestamp - LAG(timestamp, 1, timestamp) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp) < 900
            THEN 0
            ELSE 1
        END AS is_new_convo
    FROM ordered_messages 
) SELECT * FROM conversations_identified
```

How can I then form a group of messages from where `is_new_convo = 1` to the last subsequent `is_new_convo = 0`?

Here is [some sample data](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iWFfX5C4Pc8nDRmyjtnUuB/11) and [the expected result](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8pKszUkRE2Vd9MVMMJf5B5/1).

Comment: Post some example data.

Comment: @AllanWind The problem with example data for this question is that the minimum amount of sample data would have to be quite large to fully demonstrate the problem. Is there a good external website I can use where I can share some sample data and the expected output? (and preferably which also has an interface for testing queries, as this might be useful for people answering)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question

Comment: db fiddle is what I usually use and with example data I am thinking 5 rows with 3 columns.  It will help you greatly engage people that can help you.

Comment: Thanks! I've added a couple links now. Wasn't sure where the best place in the question to put them would be, since they rely on code given near the end of the question but use sample data that would be useful to know at the start of the question. I've left them at the end for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take the sum of the `is_new_convo` column from the start to a certain row, you get the number of times a new conversation has been formed, resulting in an ID that is unique for all messages in a conversation (since `is_new_convo` is 0 for messages continuing a conversation, they result in the same conversation ID). Using this, we can find the conversation ID for all messages, then group them together for `group_concat`. This doesn't require referencing the original table multiple times, so the 'WITH' clauses aren't needed.

```
SELECT group_concat(content, CHAR(10)) as conversation
FROM (
    SELECT content, timestamp,
        SUM(is_new_convo) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp) as conversation_id
    FROM (
        SELECT content, timestamp,
            CASE
                WHEN timestamp - LAG(timestamp, 1, timestamp) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp) < 900
                THEN 0
                ELSE 1
            END AS is_new_convo
        FROM messages
    )
) GROUP BY conversation_id
```